# Covaration of independent Brownian Motions is zero

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $B, B'$ be two independent Brownian motions. It can be shown that $BB'$ is a martingale. My lecture notes say that because of the martingale property the covariation of $B$ and $B'$ is zero. Why does this hold?

Answer (score 7):

This is a consequence of the property that for continuous local martingales $B, B'$ we have that $(\langle B, B' \rangle_t)$ is the unique process s.t. $(BB' - \langle B, B' \rangle)_t$ is a continuous local martingale