# Calculating quadratic covariance

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

How can i calculate quadratic covariance $<t^{2}B^{1}_{t},t^{3}B^{2}_{t}>_{T}$ when $B^{1} ,B^{2}$ is independent brownian motion.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Itô-formula for time dependent functions to get
$$t^2B^1_t=\int_0^t2sB^1_s\Bbb ds+\int_0^ts^2\Bbb dB^1_s
$$ and analogous for $t^3B^2_t$. As the first integral is a finite variation process you can neglect it in the quadratic covariation and analogous for $t^3B^2_t$. This leads us to
$$\langle t^{2}B^{1}_{t},t^{3}B^{2}_{t}\rangle_{T}=\langle \int_0^ts^2\Bbb dB^1_s,\int_0^ts^3\Bbb dB^2_s\rangle_{T}= \int_0^Ts^5\Bbb d\langle B^1,B^2\rangle_{s}.
$$
Since the [quadratic covariation for two independent Brownian motions is the constant zero function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2840615/covaration-of-independent-brownian-motions-is-zero) $\langle B^1,B^2\rangle_{s}=0$, the result is zero.